# Trouble with logical PHP when posting from Android

Tags: php, android, sql

I am trying to post information to a table and depending on if the data is from the emulator or from my phone, I want to post it in two different places. If I post from my phone, it goes into the right table but if I post from my emulator it also goes into the table that is for my phone. So, this leads me to finding that for some reason this is true for my emulator for some reason:

```
$_POST['location']!="-1.0    -1.0"
```

I copied and pasted the value "-1.0    -1.0" from the table into the logical expression. For some reason $_POST['location'] is not the right value. Syntax? Here is more of my php code below:

```
if($_POST['location']!="-1.0    -1.0" && $_POST['location']!=""){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO names_gps (Name,Location) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[location]')";

//however, in the table names_gps I get "-1.0    -1.0"

if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";


 } else {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO names (Name,Location) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[location]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
        {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
echo "1 record added";
 }
```

Can someone see where I made an error here?

Comment: Can you post the output that's in $_POST.  You may have to do something like   $requestBody    = file_get_contents('php://input');  and look up against $requestBody

Comment: hmm, I had trouble getting this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the Android code so that if it couldn't get the gps location it returned an empty string. Then modified the php to:

```
if($_POST['location']!=""){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO names_gps (Name,Location) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[location]')";
```

Well it works for what I am looking for, any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

may i know what is the type of field Location,

please make sure that the location field must be of **varchar** type having length as per your requirement...

say **varchar(30)**

this may resolves your problem

Comment: everything gets posted as a string to php from android and then it gets converted into a field in SQL (like varchar or whatever). At this point, it is still a string in php and so the field wouldn't matter. At least this is my understanding